# How to find identical columns in multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a simpler way to find matching column names in multiple tables?

The only way I know how to do this currently is to check each table individually but some tables have a bunch of columns and I know my human eye can miss things.

Comment: Sorry about that! but yes for SQL Server

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You should know your database and just looking for column names that occur in multiple tables doesn't seem very helpful. If your database is based in technical IDs, you may find that the column name ID is used in about every table. If the database is based on composite keys, you may find half of the involved columns in the results. If a supplier has a name and and employee has a name, you'll find NAME twice, but it's different names, so who cares?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT      c.name, string_agg(t.name, ', ')
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
group by c.name
```

Comment: So since this is for SQL Server, I want to play around with this one. Say I have about four different tables I want to compare identical columns in. Each of the table names would go into the parenthasis after the 'string_agg()' Correct?

Comment: that is correct. you will get result in two columns. first is actual column name, second is comma separated list of tables where this column exists

Comment: Ahh I see, so this is only is you already know which column you're trying to look for. 
There isn't anything to check each table and return all identical columns?

Comment: Joshua Huezo: The query gets you all columns with all the tables they exist in. If you want to look for specific tables or column names, add a `WHERE` clause. If you only want to see column_names that occur in more than one table, add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `information_schema.columns`.  For instance, to get all column names in multiple tables:

```
select column_name, string_agg( concat(table_schema, '.', table_name), ',')
from information_schema.columns
group by column_name
having count(*) > 1;
```

The `information_schema` views are actually standard and available in many databases, including SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle

Use DBA_TAB COLUMNS or ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table it contains names of columns with table name and other details

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh sorry about that! :/ 
But it's for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir's answer is right and specific to SQL Server.

Another good answer is to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to retrieve what you're looking for.  INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a standard follow by some DBMS to provides a common  view for common objects.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15